# Creating elements with jquery .click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm currently working on a small "dress-up" type feature for a friend's website, but have run into a logic issue.

The items that you may use to dress your avatar must be bought. Bought items are loaded on screen for users to click (as an image) and when clicked should create a jqueryui draggable inside a div. The problem I've run into, is I can't figure out how to make it create that exact image inside the div.

I guess what I'm looking for is a way to recreate the image clicked inside the div as a draggable. Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo-code:

```
image.click(function() {
    div.append($(this).clone());
});
```